# How can I register facebook users on my site ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find a walk through on how to register users via facebook onto my site.

The facebook developers site keeps confusing me and I was hoping there where easier tutorials to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stephen,
It can be a little complicated.

You have to combine the documentation at:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Boiling it down to the simplest case:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'yourAppID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
  </script>
     <fb:registration
        fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'},
        {'name':'favorite_car','description':'What is your favorite car?',
        'type':'text'}]" redirect-uri="Your processing URL">
     </fb:registration>
</body>
</html>
```

Facebook will return an encrypted form field with all the user data called "signed Request"  You will need to decrypt this field with your secret key.  There is an PHP example at the bottom of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Comment: Hi im trying this but now im getting the error That 'redirect_uri' isn't allowed for that client_id.

Comment: The redirect_URI has to be in the site domain you specified when you created the application on Facebook.

Comment: found out what was wrong. this site url was not set up cheers